# Compiling c++ project with 3rd party lib to WebAssembly

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten

I have a simple c++ project which includes [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). I'm able to compile the project on my own machine but having trouble to compile it to webassembly with emscripten.

Project structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── HelloWasm
│       └── my_lib.h
└── src
    ├── main.cpp
    └── my_lib.cpp
```

File contents:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0 )

project( HelloWasm )

# flags

# include files
include_directories( ./include .include/HelloWasm ./src )

# target
add_executable( HelloWasm ./src/main.cpp ./src/my_lib.cpp )

# 3rd party libs
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

**include/HelloWasm/my_lib.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;

class MyLib
{
private:
protected:
public:
    MyLib()
    {
    }
    ~MyLib()
    {
    }
    void eigen_test();
};
```

src/main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "HelloWasm/my_lib.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MyLib my_lib;
    my_lib.eigen_test();
}
```

src/my_lib.cpp

```
#include "HelloWasm/my_lib.h"

void MyLib::eigen_test()
{
    MatrixXd m(2, 2);
    m(0, 0) = 3;
    m(1, 0) = 2.5;
    m(0, 1) = -1;
    m(1, 1) = m(1, 0) + m(0, 1);
    cout << '\n'
         << m << endl;
}
```

### Compiling the project successfully locally:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make

➜ ./HelloWasm

  3  -1
2.5 1.5
```

### Errors when trying to compile to webassemply

(I tried following the steps provided in the [emscripten docs](https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html))

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
emcmake cmake ..
```

output:

```
configure: cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/me/programming/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR="/Users/me/programming/emsdk/node/12.9.1_64bit/bin/node"
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE


-- Build files have been written to: /Users/me/programming/sandbox/cpp_sandbox/so_question_project/build
```

Now running make:

```
➜  emmake make
make: make
Scanning dependencies of target HelloWasm
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/HelloWasm.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/HelloWasm.dir/src/my_lib.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable HelloWasm
[100%] Built target HelloWasm
```

Obviously that did not create a .wasm file...

Doing the following:

```
em++ CMakeFiles/HelloWasm.dir/src/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/HelloWasm.dir/src/my_lib.cpp.o -o helloWasm.js
```

output:

```
em++: warning: CMakeFiles/HelloWasm.dir/src/main.cpp.o is not a valid input file [-Winvalid-input]
em++: warning: CMakeFiles/HelloWasm.dir/src/my_lib.cpp.o is not a valid input file [-Winvalid-input]
em++: error: no input files
note that input files without a known suffix are ignored, make sure your input files end with one of: ('.c', '.i', '.cpp', '.cxx', '.cc', '.c++', '.CPP', '.CXX', '.C', '.CC', '.C++', '.ii', '.m', '.mi', '.mm', '.mii', '/dev/null', '.bc', '.o', '.obj', '.lo', '.dylib', '.so', '.a', '.ll', '.h', '.hxx', '.hpp', '.hh', '.H', '.HXX', '.HPP', '.HH')
```

What am I missing here...?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
em++ CMakeFiles/HelloWasm.dir/src/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/HelloWasm.dir/src/my_lib.cpp.o -o helloWasm.js
```

To:

```
em++ CMakeFiles/HelloWasm.dir/src/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/HelloWasm.dir/src/my_lib.cpp -o helloWasm.js
```

Emscripten can't compile `my_lib.cpp.o` because it's already compiled to machine code (it's an object file).  You have to use a `.cpp` file, not `.cpp.o`.

Comment: there is not such file: `CMakeFiles/HelloWasm.dir/src/my_lib.cpp` only `my_lib.o`. if I run:


`em++ src/main.cpp src/my_lib.cpp -o helloWasm.js` it does not find the my_lib.h:


```src/main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'HelloWasm/my_lib.h' file not found
#include "HelloWasm/my_lib.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
em++: error: '/Users/me/programming/emsdk/upstream/bin/clang++ -target wasm32-...
```

Comment: Having a `my_lib.cpp` and `my_lib.h` is confusing me.  Anyway, you have to tell emscripten to compile a single `.cpp` file.  If you need to include `my_lib.h` in that file, do so with `#include <my_lib.h>`. **EDIT:** Put the FULL path of `my_lib.h` inside `#include <...>`.

Answer (score -1):

I have a suggestion for you.

First, you can put your lib files (`my_lib.h and my_lib.cpp`) on same directory.

Second, you can create a folder for your applications (`HelloWasm`) and put your executable codes (`main.cpp`) in this folder.

Finally, you can create `CMakeLists.txt` file for each folder.

---

## This is your new directory tree:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Applications
│   └── HelloWasm
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       └── main.cpp
└── Libraries
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── my_lib.h
    └── my_lib.cpp
```

## CMakeLists.txt (the first one) :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(LIBRARYANDAPPS)

#This function is starting build and looking all folders.

function( start_build )
  file( GLOB_RECURSE components "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*/CMakeLists.txt" )
  foreach( component ${components} )
    get_filename_component( path ${component} PATH )
    add_subdirectory( ${path} )
  endforeach( )
endfunction( )

start_build()
```

## CMakeLists.txt (for HelloWasm):

```
#You can add Emscripten flags like this.
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} \
    -std=c++11 --bind \
    -s USE_WEBGL2=1 -s FULL_ES3=1 --memory-init-file 0")

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})

include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Libraries")

ADD_EXECUTABLE(HelloWasm main.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(HelloWasm MyLib Eigen)
```

## CMakeLists.txt (for Library):

```
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})

ADD_LIBRARY(MyLib STATIC my_lib.cpp my_lib.h)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MyLib Eigen)
```

---

With these edits, you can create bigger projects, libraries. And I think more useful like this.